# Highlighting the current line number in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to highlight **only** the current line number (in the left hand coloumn) in vim, without highlighting the background of the current line? Ideally, I would Like to make the current line number **bold**.

Comment: I don't know about that, but you do realize it's at the bottom of the window, yes?

Comment: It's not at the bottom of my window. The bottom of my window only contains the text --INSERT--. How do you get the current document position to show at the bottom of the window?

Comment: I didn't realize it was not on by default, but apparently `set ruler` could be a command for that: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/show-line-and-column-numbers-in-vim-7-0-a-478231/

Comment: Yep. set ruler works for my setup (MacVim on Lion), and it's not on by default. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are two groups that determine highlighting of line displayed when `&cursorline` option is active: `CursorLine` and `CursorLineNR`. First is used to highlight the whole line, second for the line number. So to achieve what you want you must

1. Clear the highlighting of `CursorLine`: just `hi clear CursorLine` *after any `:colorscheme` and `set background=` call*.

   ```
   hi clear CursorLine
   augroup CLClear
       autocmd! ColorScheme * hi clear CursorLine
   augroup END
   ```
2. Set the highlighting of `CursorLineNR` if it is not set in your colorscheme:

   ```
   hi CursorLineNR cterm=bold
   augroup CLNRSet
       autocmd! ColorScheme * hi CursorLineNR cterm=bold
   augroup END
   ```

   (better to check whether it is already set in the colorscheme, maybe it will look better in that case).

You can join both autocommands in one of course.

`CursorLineNR` has been added relatively recently around version `7.3.488`.

Comment: Clever solution. What is the asterisk for (after the autocmd! ColorScheme)? I'm not well versed in vimscript.

Comment: @ChristopherGreen `:h :autocmd`: it would show you that it can only be pattern. A single asterisk means that this autocommand will be executed for every colorscheme.

Comment: @ZyX Thanks for your great answer, but `CursorLineNR` work for all Vim versions? I'm trying to follow your answer but I can't highlight the current line number using Vim 7.3.

Comment: @Yang Generally the best way to answer this question is using `hg annotate` on the file containing relevant documentation (in this case it is `runtime/doc/syntax.txt`). `hg annotate runtime/doc/syntax.txt | grep CursorLineNr` shows that this tag was first defined in revision https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/changeset/2cfb68fa26cd10c54b17f833ba67e3f408c48ca4 which is just after 7.3.487. In this case CursorLineNr is also shown in log, revisions corresponds to vim 7.3.479.

Comment: @ZyX Thanks for your explanation to Mercurial. Updating to 7.4a solved my problem. Do you mind helping me with another question? http://superuser.com/questions/622171/vim-turn-off-syntax-highlight-for-some-elements Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04's Vim stops at patch 429 =(

Comment: Thanks for mentioning to put it after colorscheme.

Answer (score 21):

You want to look at

```
:se cursorline
```

and perhaps even/also

```
:se cursorcolumn
```

Comment: How to turn that off?

Comment: @Pétur as with any other option, so `:se cul!` or e.g. `:se nocursorline`

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me:

```
highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=NONE
set cursorline
```

I'm just using this in my .vimrc after having set the color scheme. Of course you could also set a specific background color but setting all of them to NONE just highlights the line number (i.e. makes it brighter).

I guess you could just use `:hi CursorLine cterm=NONE` but I just wanted to make sure I'm making everything transparent (gvim included).

With `CursorLineNR` I was then able to set the foreground and background colors of the highlighted number.

I'm only writing this because for me it worked without any autocommands and it may be what most people require.

Comment: This is a nice low-impact way to highlight the line. Love it!

Comment: Straight forward and elegant.

Answer (score 15):

You can set cursorline to highlight only the numbers

> ```
> 'cursorlineopt' 'culopt' string (default: "number,line")                        
>                         local to window                                         
>                         {not available when compiled without the +syntax        
>                         feature}                                                
>         Comma separated list of settings for how 'cursorline' is displayed.     
>         Valid values:                                                           
>         "line"          Highlight the text line of the cursor with              
>                         CursorLine hl-CursorLine.                               
>         "screenline"    Highlight only the screen line of the cursor with       
>                         CursorLine hl-CursorLine.                               
>         "number"        Highlight the line number of the cursor with            
>                         CursorLineNr hl-CursorLineNr.
> ```

And to override your colorscheme [use autocmd](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f)

So, the following works:

```
set cursorline
set cursorlineopt=number
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight CursorLineNr cterm=bold term=bold gui=bold
```

Comment: Thanks. The new underlined numbers was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me to highlight the line number and not the rest of the line:

`highlight CursorLineNr cterm=NONE ctermbg=15 ctermfg=8 gui=NONE guibg=#ffffff guifg=#d70000`

Answer (score 0):

The help for [highlight-groups](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#highligth-groups) does not mention an exclusive "number of current line" syntax group, so the official answer might be **no**.

You may want to take a look in the [cursorline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cursorline%27) option which highlights the entire line, if it helps.