# Change vim left side bar color

Tags: vim, customization

Hello does anybody know how can i change the color of the bar left of the numbers?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edOe6.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237289/vim-configure-line-number-coloring

Comment: Thanks, I checked that but the issue is on the left side of the number line. I might add that the issue is only when i am outside of a tmux session, if i am in tmux that white bar overlay is not there anymore, maybe is a terminal thing and not a vim thing

Comment: It is a colorscheme issue apparently with other colorscheme this issue is not there.