# Vim Save Line Number Coloring

Tags: vim

I'm trying to change the default Line Number coloring.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237289/vim-configure-line-number-coloring) I found that I can change the line number by issuing something like:

```
:highlight LineNr guifg=Red
```

But, how do I save this to my `~/.vimrc`?

In my `~/.vimrc`, if I added:

```
highlight LineNr guifg=Red
```

the new Vim window is still having the yellow line number.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

From [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f):

```
augroup MyColors
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme default highlight LineNr guifg=red
augroup END
```